# Consumir servicio web local desde mi dispositivo android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webservice

estoy trabajando con un Servicio Web hecho en ASP.NET, el problema es que no puedo hacer funcionar el url localhost desde mi dispositivo android, he utilizado la dirección IP de mi ordenador de esta forma en el navegador móvil: http://192.168.x.x:8433/odata/Usuarios o http://192.168.x.x:8080/odata/Usuarios pero no hay respuesta, también probé con deshabilitar el firewall.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_user);

    mensaje= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);

    btnBuscar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);
    btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new ObtenerDatosUsuario().execute("localhost:8433/odata/Usuarios");
        }
    });
}

private class ObtenerDatosUsuario extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
             reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer resultado = new StringBuffer();

            String linea = "";
            while ((linea = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                resultado.append(linea);
            }

            String resultadoString = resultado.toString();

            JSONObject resultadoJSON = new JSONObject(resultadoString);


            int id = resultadoJSON.getInt("Id");
            String nombre = resultadoJSON.getString("Nombre");
            String correo = resultadoJSON.getString("Email");

            return "Id: " + id + " - " + "Nombre: " + nombre + " - " + "Correo: " + correo;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(connection != null)
            {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try
            {
                if(reader != null)
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        Log.i("ServicioRest","onPostExecute");
        Mensaje.setText(result);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        Log.i("ServicioRest","onPreExecute");
        info.setText("Se esta obteniendo la información.");
    }
}
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿No hay respuesta donde y de que? En el código que muestras creas una URL, pero luego esa URL hay que mandarla al servidor y capturar la respuesta. ¿Lo estás haciendo así? Muestra el código, ponle un Logcat y pon en la pregunta el error que estás recibiendo.

Comment: He agregado mi código, lo hago de esa forma pero como es un servicio web local, no puedo realizar consultas desde mi dispositivo android con la URL "localhost:8433". He investigado que debo cambiar mi URL localhost por la dirección IP de mi computadora, pero no ha funcionado.

Comment: Mira, creo que esta respuesta [te puede ayudar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5806384/5587982) se propone en ella usar la dirección IP del localhost, que podría ser `10.0.2.2`, si no es esa la puedes averiguar trasteando en tu configuración internet o a través del comando `netstat` o parecidos. La IP del localhost suele empezar siempre por `10`. Saludos.

Comment: pureba de realizar la peticion de la api con la extension postman de chrome

Comment: NO hay respuesta porque probablemente solo  puedes acceder a la ip desde tu pc, asegura primeramente que puedas acceder externamente la url, es importante que revises en el LogCat, ahí encontraras la información del problema. Si puedes acceder a el WS realiza lo que comenta Webserveis , asegura enviar los datos correctos, si es .NET, tal vez puedes   revisar la descripción de tu método WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

Pues podrías utilizar las librerías de HTTP de Apache para facilitar el trabajo y después utilizarla para hacer una petición web:

En este caso, tienes que enviar tu objeto URL al objeto HttpURLConnection y abrir la conexión y especificarle el tipo del método (Get) y recoges la respuesta y ya la tratas.

```
 public  String petitionHTTPGET(String page) {
    String response = "";

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {           
        url = new URL(page);        
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();          
        response = getStringFromInputStream(inputStream);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("RESTExample", "MalformedURLException");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e("RESTExample", "ProtocolException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("RESTExample", "IOException");
    }finally{
        connection.disconnect();
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("RESTExample", "IOException");
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

En este otro ejemplo harías una petición POST y tratarías las líneas devueltas, que en el ejemplo van en XML.

```
    private String httpPostRequest(String httpPost, String xmlToSend) {     

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(httpPost);

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xmlToSend));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        String xml = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            xml += line;
        }
        return xml;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("RESExample", "IOException");
    }
    return "";
}
```